# Do I need more space?

Tags: c++, xcode

I have code that is supposed to separate a string into 3 length sections:

> ABCDEFG should be ABC DEF G

However, I have an extremely long string and I keep getting the

> terminate called without an active exception

When I cut the length of the string down, it seems to work. Do I need more space? I thought when using a string I didn't have to worry about space.

```
int main ()
{
    string code, default_Code, start_C;
    default_Code = "TCAATGTAACGCGCTACCCGGAGCTCTGGGCCCAAATTTCATCCACT";         
    start_C      = "AUG";

    code         = default_Code;

    for (double j = 0; j < code.length(); j++) {  //insert spacing here
        code.insert(j += 3, 1, ' ');
    }
    cout << code;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Think about the case when code.length() == 2. You're inserting a space somewhere over the string. I'm not sure but it would be okay if `for(int j=0; j+3 < code.length(); j++)`.

Comment: YOU ARE THE BOMB!!!!   ED. On a quick note, should I change double j back to an int j?

Comment: @user1046825: Change it to `int` rather `unsigned int`, length of a string is never going to be `double` which you compare to. Also, the problem is exactly the same as quoted in the answer, your `string::insert()` throws an `out_of_range` exception(position of insertion is past the length of string) which do you do not catch and hence the abnormal termination.

Comment: @user1046825, yes, you should: integer math is faster than floating-point math, and at some point adding 1 to a double won't do anything anymore. And while you're there, don't forget to click the checkmark on the left of the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @zneak: do you know **when** adding one to a double does nothing? It's 9,007,199,254,740,992 ... s/he is not going to have that problem until the string is nine millions of gigabytes.

Comment: @6502, I did not know indeed. Would it have been better to tell to leave the double as is?

Comment: @zneak: No... suggesting using an integer is a good idea. The precision (in this context) however is not a good reason. An integer much sooner than a double will have problem with that (at 2**31-1 adding one will most probably flip to -2**31).

Answer (score 2):

This is some fairly confusing code. You are looping through a string and looping until you reach the end of the string. However, inside the loop you are not only modifying the string you are looping through, but you also change the loop variable when you say j += 3.

It happens to work for any string with a multiple of 3 letters, but you are not correctly handling other cases.

Here is a working example of the for loop that is a bit more clear it what it's doing:

```
// We skip 4 each time because we added a space.
for (int j = 3; j < code.length(); j += 4) 
{
   code.insert(j, 1, ' ');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Could I bother you for another question that I have been working on for over a week now??

Comment: If you don't mind...I now have to repeat that code 2 more times, but I have to "chop" off the first letter every time I do that...

Comment: That should be a fairly similar solution, except you will now need to be careful about your loop counter when removing the character.

Comment: Could you help with some pseudocode. I have been trying to work on this for over a week and have gotten nowhere fast, using different techniques that all end up the same...

Answer (score 0):

You are using an extremely inefficient method to do such an operation. Every time you insert a space you are moving all the remaining part of the string forward and this means that the total number of operations you will need is in the order of `o(n**2)`.

You can instead do this transormation with a single `o(n)` pass by using a read-write approach:

```
// input string is assumed to be non-empty
std::string new_string((old_string.size()*4-1)/3);
int writeptr = 0, count = 0;
for (int readptr=0,n=old_string.size(); readptr<n; readptr++) {
    new_string[writeptr++] = old_string[readptr];
    if (++count == 3) {
        count = 0;
        new_string[writeptr++] = ' ';
    }
}
```

A similar algorithm can be written also to work "inplace" instead of creating a new string, simply you have to first enlarge the string and then work backward.

Note also that while it's true that for a string you don't need to care about allocation and deallocation still there are limits about the size of a string object (even if probably you are not hitting them... your version is so slow that it would take forever to get to that point on a modern computer).